# Rails only save record if fields not empty for nested form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

In my Rails application I have a `Kid` model and an `Allergy` model where a `Kid` has_many `Allergies`. I have also created a nested form so that the `allergy` fields are in the `kid` form when creating a new `kid`. This is what I have in my `kid` controller:

```
def new
   @kid = Kid.new
   allergy = @kid.allergies.build
end
```

and this is in my index.html.erb nested in my create `kid`form:

```
<%= f.fields_for :allergies, Allergy.new do |u| %>
     <%= u.label :description, "Description", class: "control-label" %>    
     <%= u.text_field :description, class: "input-sm form-control" %>
     <%= u.label :symptoms, "Symptoms", class: "control-label",  %>    
     <%= u.text_field :symptoms, class: "input-sm form-control" %>
<%end%>
```

This works fine for inserting just one `allergy` record into the `Allergy` model, however I want to be able to list up to 5 `allergy` inputs, and only insert those ones that a user fills, as a `kid` could have a variable amount of `allergies`.

I used this article: http://vicfriedman.github.io/blog/2015/07/18/create-multiple-objects-from-single-form-in-rails/

However, I could not make this work for a nested form. All help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Have you try `:reject_if` ? http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to get multiple nested forms for your relations you will need to build the number of related items you want to display in the form, something like:

```
def new
    @kid = Kid.new
    5.times do
        @kid.allergies.build
    end
end
```

to then reject saving any empty relations in the database, in the model you could use something like:

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :allergies, reject_if: ->(allergy){ allergy['description'].blank? && allergy['symptoms'].blank? }
```